# Fonts are suddenly bolder in Firefox 109.0

Tags: firefox, browser, fonts, rendering, bug

Over the last few days I've noticed that the fonts rendered by Firefox are bolder than usual. This affects me both as a user, as the fonts are jarring and noticeably harder to read, and as a web developer who does most of his development in Firefox, as it points to an increase in stylistic inconsistency between Firefox and Chrome, meaning that my users are essentially experiencing two different versions of all the sites I design.

Checking Firefox's update history in `Help > About` tells me that it was updated to Firefox 109 on January 17, which roughly coincides with the time I noticed this issue. However, checking the update's (very minimal) changelog doesn't mention anything about changes to fonts or typefaces.

**Is there any confirmation of if and when exactly this change was implemented in Firefox, or is something else responsible for it? If it is a result of the update, what was the reasoning for it?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update: this change has now been reverted

Following on from the discussion in [the original bug report](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1803154), this change was reverted in [the following commit](https://hg.mozilla.org/releases/mozilla-beta/rev/1dc7fc9e7fc4), meaning future versions of Firefox will render fonts just like version 108 and previous did. Thanks to all those involved, including those who voiced their opposition to the change on the bug report, and credit where it's due to Mozilla and the Firefox devs for responding to and resolving the issue in less than a week.

To get an update that contains the fix, you can temporarily switch to the Beta update channel by installing the [latest Beta build of Firefox here](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/channel/desktop/), where the fix has already been pushed. Beta is the most stable update channel after the standard Release channel. A Release channel update with the fix will probably be issued in [about a month](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Release_Management/Release_Process#Release_timeline).

**If you previously applied the workaround below, remember to undo it by going through the same steps, but changing `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.gamma` back to `-1` instead of `2200`. Doing this before you update will make sure you actually notice the difference, and can confirm that the update worked for you.**

---

Although not listed in the changelog, this was indeed a change introduced in Firefox 109.0, and is due to the "fixing" of a bug which previously caused Windows Cleartype settings to be ignored. The problem is that Firefox seems to be the only browser that has bothered to fix this bug, making it look more inconsistent with Chrome than it ever and resulting in text that is jarring to read.

As a short-term solution, you can try running Windows 10's Clear Type Tuner (which for me only resulted in a larger discrepancy between the boldness of header and body text) or following the instructions below. For a more permanent fix, see the final section.

---

### Workaround: reverting the change for your system

1. In Windows' Registry Editor, navigate to the `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Avalon.Graphics\DISPLAY1` key
2. Look for the `GammaNote` value, and take note of its data in brackets (it will likely be `2200`)
3. Navigate to `about:config` from the Firefox address bar, and search for *"gamma"*.
4. Modify the value of the `gfx.font_rendering.cleartype_params.gamma` config key to the value previously noted, and click the <kbd>✓</kbd> to apply the change.
5. Finally, navigate to `about:profiles` and click <kbd>Restart normally</kbd> to restart Firefox

<sup>[Thanks to Fanolian](https://www.reddit.com/r/firefox/comments/10ed7o2/comment/j4qar9y/?utm_source=reddit&utm_medium=web2x&context=3) for providing the basis for these instructions and finding the relevant Registry keys.</sup>

---

### Permanent fix: reverting the change for future versions of Firefox

The above instructions are a short-term fix for individual power users who are bothered enough by the change to revert it - for the vast majority of Firefox users, this change will be the new default, which means unless it's reverted by Mozilla itself, the new uglier fonts will be the new Firefox experience for every version going forward.

**Therefore, if you're a web developer or just someone who values a consistent browser experience across Windows, I recommend voicing your views on the change via the [relevant Bugzilla issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1803154)**. With enough users opposed to it (which seems to be quite a lot, if Reddit is anything to go by) there's a chance the devs will see sense and revert the behaviour to look readable and consistent with other browsers once again.

Comment: A better fix is for Chrome to honour the Windows Clear type settings as intended.

Comment: @DavidPostill Not necessarily, because as stated this "fix" results in text that is actively harder to read, so on its own isn't even complete. Even if that were solved, convincing Chrome to fix this would be the tidiest option in an idealistic world, but an unlikely one given we're talking about Google. With 5-10% of market share it's arguably Firefox's responsibility to follow the market leader, if only for pragmatic reasons, because it's highly unlikely any move Firefox makes will influence Chrome to follow suit, and the end result will be that users and web devs suffer.

Comment: Well I'm on 109.0 and have Clear Type set up correctly. No issues with Firefox readability.